# How to send images to Stripe Checkout Session in Laravel 8

Tags: php, stripe-payments, laravel-8

I am having issues trying to send images using Stripe Checkout Session, I am using Laravel 8, with the Backpack Admin panel plugin. I am using Stripe's prebuilt checkout page. Here is the controller code for stripe.

Stripe Controller Method:

```
/* Sends the stripe key, and payment info to the stripe api */
    public function payment() {
        // Initialize the array for stripe checkout session

        $line_items = array();

        foreach (Cart::content() as $item) {
            $product = Product::find($item->id);
            $temp_items = array(
                  'price_data' => [
                    'currency' => 'usd',
                    'product_data' => [
                      'name' => $item->name,
                      'images' => ["http://127.0.0.1:8000/$product->image"],
                    ],
                    'unit_amount' => $item->price * 100,
                  ],
                  'quantity' => $item->qty,
            );

            array_push($line_items, $temp_items);
        }

        // Sets up the businesses secret key to receive the payment
        \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));

        // Sets up payment method, and product information
        $session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create ([
            'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
            'line_items' => [[$line_items]],
            'mode' => 'payment',
            'success_url' => 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/',
            'cancel_url' => 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/cart',
        ]);

        return response()->json(['id' => $session->id]);
    }
```

Images doesn't show in stripe's prebuilt checkout page:
[image]

My images are stored in public/uploads

Here is how the database is set up
[image]

Lastly here is the migrations file for products:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateProductsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */

     public function up()
     {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name')->unique();
            $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('slug')->default('');
            $table->double('price', 2);
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->text('content');
            $table->integer('quantity');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('products');
    }
}
```

Ask me if you need any more information.

Comment: The images have to be at a public URL — Stripe will access them and re-host them on a CDN, so the images on the actual Checkout page come from the CDN and not through loading the images on your site. So basically this can't work if you're only hosting on localhost, since Stripe can't access your images. You could use something like ngrok to get a public URL for your site in development.

Comment: So once I get my site live will it work?

Comment: I would assume so yep, or you can use ngrok too to test this in development.

Comment: Thanks! I will try it! Happy Holidays!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stripe Does not let you show local images, or the ones that you have stored in your disk, try storing those images online and fetching it from there, or some cdn links